# Stop computer from sleeping

Tags: 14.04, suspend

Okay, so I'm new to trying out Linux. I want to get more comfortable with it but when basic things like stopping the computer from falling asleep on me become impossible to fix from a "I can't find anything in settings, googling and trying the results that come up fail" standpoint, it becomes pretty hard to want to keep giving it a chance.

For example, I'm watching a YouTube video. I want to sit back and watch, not have to move my mouse on a whim. And from what I THINK I've gathered, Caffeine only stops it from happening when I fullscreen the video. Well I hardly fullscreen videos and I don't want to start just because of this.

Besides, even if I DID start full screening videos, it wouldn't help with Skype. I'll be in a Skype call talking to people and out of nowhere, boom! I'm disconnected! Why? Because the dumb thing fell asleep during a call.

I've searched and searched to no avail. But the thing is, I SHOULDN'T HAVE TO be searching for some fix to this. Why is the OS so primitive to not handle this correctly? Am I just stupid and blind to the fix for this or is my aggravation justified? Please help.

Edit: I should point out I don't want the screen to never sleep. If I walk way from the computer I want it to, to save battery. Because if I walk away from my computer it won't be while in a Skype call or with a video playing. It's obvious tasks like those I want it to not sleep, and let it do so when not doing them. I **DON'T** want to disable sleep forever.

Comment: This normally depends on your desktop environment, not the OS per-se. Do you use vanilla Ubuntu as it gets installed or have you installed LXDE or KDE?

Comment: I have vanilla Ubuntu.

Comment: with your edit it becomes unclear whether you're after screen or computer sleep settings or both? Could you clarify, please.

Comment: Both of them, I don't want the screen turning off or it going to sleep while watching a video/movie/being in a Skype call, etc.

Comment: If you're still not satisfied with your current solution, I recommend giving Keep.Awake a shot.
Read the answer recommending Keep.Awake here:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/577862/how-to-temporarily-disable-sleep-and-hibernate-from-the-command-line?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 3):

In the top right corner, there is a menu with the item "System settings". This will open a screen with various configuration items. The one you want is "Power". Here you can set the screen dimming behaviour.

Comment: I added an edit to my original post which I think addresses your reply. Let me know if what you're talking about is different.

Answer (score 0):

There's a section in the system settings called `Brightness and lock` where you can set how long the computer can be idle before locking.

Comment: Please read my entire post.

Comment: @hobox I'm fairly new to Linux myself, so I'm not sure how to make certain processes keep the display on. Sorry.