# Is there a way to disable sleep of a remote computer from command line?

Tags: 12.04, power-management, remote

It's an Ubuntu 12.0.4 computer that I have access only through ssh. How to prevent it from going to sleep?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/66723/how-do-i-modify-the-options-for-the-power-button has all you need (or if not the exact option you want to change it will guide you to how to find it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to temporarily disable sleep and hibernate from the command line](http://askubuntu.com/questions/577862/how-to-temporarily-disable-sleep-and-hibernate-from-the-command-line)